# Django nested OuterRef

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Trying to understand and get working nested `OuterRef` on simple example (just for this test)

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Issue(models.Model):
    due_date = models.DateField()


class UserIssue(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assigned_to = models.DateField()


class Calendar(models.Model):
    calendar_date = models.DateField()

    @classmethod
    def report(cls):
        main_qs = cls.objects.all()
        second_subquery = (
            Issue.objects.filter(due_date=OuterRef(OuterRef("calendar_date")))
            .values("due_date")
            .annotate(count=Count("due_date"))
            .values("count")
        )
        first_subquery = (
            UserIssue.objects.filter(assigned_to=OuterRef("calendar_date"))
            .annotate(today_due_date=Sum(second_subquery))
            .values("today_due_date")
        )

        qs = main_qs.annotate(today_due_date=first_subquery)
        print(qs.query)
        return qs
```

When call `Calendar.report()` got `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "users_calendar.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` and have no idea how to fix it.

Printed SQL is

```sql
SELECT "users_calendar"."id",
       "users_calendar"."calendar_date",
       (SELECT SUM((SELECT COUNT(U0."due_date") AS "count"
                    FROM "users_issue" U0
                    WHERE U0."due_date" = ("users_calendar"."calendar_date")
                    GROUP BY U0."due_date")) AS "today_due_date"
        FROM "users_userissue" V0
        WHERE V0."assigned_to" = ("users_calendar"."calendar_date")
        GROUP BY V0."id") AS "today_due_date"
FROM "users_calendar"
```

and when manually add

```sql
GROUP BY "users_calendar"."id";
```

then it works so my question is how to achieve the same using ORM?

Thanks

Comment: Django's ORM isn't about trying to produce a specific SQL query. Could you explain the problem you are trying to solve on a higher level ?